# Pig Script toDate convertion issue resulting different output

Tags: apache-pig, bigdata

How to convert date and time using PIG? I'm trying to convert not converting into 24 hours format Input values

`30/06/2016 02:43:23 PM
 01/12/2016 12:43:23 AM`

after passing `ToDate($0,'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa')` 
Result is

`30/06/2016 02:43:23.324+05:30
 01/12/2016 12:43:23+05:30`

but expecting result as

`30/06/2016 14:43:23 
 01/12/2016 12:43:23`

can any one help me on this

Answer (score 1):

**Ref :** http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#to-date the return type of ToDate is DateTime object.

To convert a chararray date to any other format then you have to use ToString() function after getting the DateTime object.

**Input : a.csv**

```
30/06/2016 02:43:23 PM
01/12/2016 12:43:23 AM
```

**Pig Script :**

```
adataset = LOAD 'a.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (display_date:chararray);
req = FOREACH adataset GENERATE ToString(ToDate(display_date,'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a'),'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss'); 
DUMP req;
```

Comment: Murali thanks a lot for your help....its working great!!!!!                                                  is it possible to convert datetime like 30/06/16 02:43:23 PM 01/12/17 12:43:23 AM  into         (30/06/2016 14:43:23) (01/12/2016 00:43:23)

Comment: @dass : You have to specify the format accordingly, check - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html to know how to specify the formats. For your example dd/MM/yy should work.

Comment: i have to get date,year,month and min,sec,hh individually to need to change the format of Date Time yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss,  i have done splitting string get which gets into other relation??? is it possible to do it same generate statement. please find the same code of what i am trying to do in the below comment

Comment: complete = foreach tmp {        
date = ToDate($8,'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
year = (chararray)ABS(GetYear(date));
month = (chararray)ABS(GetMonth(date));
day = (chararray)ABS(GetDay(date));
hour = (chararray)ABS(GetHour(date));
min = (chararray)ABS(GetMinute(date));
sec = (chararray)ABS(GetSecond(date));
generate $0,CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(year, '-'), CONCAT(month, '-')),day),CONCAT(' ',CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(hour, ':'), CONCAT(min, ':')),sec))),,$33,$22,$2,$3,$17,$18,$21;
}

Comment: @dass : if you need - as the delimiter then specify the same in the format of ToString method. Check updated answer.

Comment: thanks for the update murali....but what i what to change is dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy/mm/dd can you help me on this??